# C++: std::vector::reserve not reserving when containing pointers

Tags: c++, stdvector

When I call `std::vector::reserve` when the identifier is of type `std::vector<Foo*>` `reserve(...)` does nothing:

```
std::vector<int*> bar;
bar.reserve(20);

//I expect bar.size to return 20...
std::size_t sz = bar.size();
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    //Do Stuff to all items!
}
```

The aforementioned `for` loop runs exactly zero times and bar.size() returns zero. I do not remember if this is also true for all other STL containers, but if so, including the behavior for std::vector: ***WHY?***

Comment: In addition to the stuff below, I think you also mean to use `std::vector<int*>::size_type` rather than just `std::size_t`. I'm not sure it matters that much, but I've seen this mentioned as a "best practices" sort of thing for STL. You can also instantiate a vector with a size parameter. I think `std::vector<int*> bar(20);` for example should allocate space for 20 integer pointers for that array.

Comment: Pedantic code like `for(std::vector<int*>::size_type i; i < sz; ++i)` drives me mad.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

.reserve() doesn't change the size of a vector.  The member function you are looking for is .resize().  reserve() is simply an optimization.  If you are going to add a bunch of things to a vector one-by-one using push_back() then telling it how many you will add using reserve() can make the code run a little bit faster.  But just calling reserve() doesn't change the size.

Answer (score 8):

[`vector::reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) changes the **capacity** of a vector, not its **size**.

[`capacity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) is how much memory has been allocated internally to hold elements of the vector. [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is how many elements have actually held by the vector. [`vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) affects the latter.

Answer (score 7):

[`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) changes the capacity of the vector, not the size. You probably want [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)